# Problem 16 Chapter 1 From Rudin: Have I Understood The Question Correctly?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

[image]

I've done part b and c of this question, but I'm not sure if I've understood part a) of this question correctly. Is it telling me to show that there are infinitely many z such that $|z - x| = |z - y| = r$, where r is any number that is greater $d/2$? Or is it saying that for any r that is greater than $d/2$,  there are infinitely many z such that $|z - x| = |z - y| = r$?

Thanks in advance. **Also, could you please avoid giving any hints on this question? I would still like to attempt it myself.**

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of the difference between your two questions ("any" is sometimes hard to parse) but most likely you want the latter.  The answer should provide infinitely many $z$ for every $r$ satisfying $r > d/2$, and not simply one value of $r$ satisfying $r > d/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your second statement is closest to what you must show. Given two points $x$ and $y$ that are distance $d$ apart, and given a particular but arbitrary $r>0$ for which $r>{d\over2}$, you need to show that there are infinitely many points $z$ that are a distance $r$ from each of the points $x$ and $y$.